# Permission based routing in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating a project using angular 6. In my project redirection based on permission and roles. I have implemented this using activate method and it works all cases except one.

The problem is landing page is also based on permission and it fails on landing page if user doest not have permission.

```
     { path: '', redirectTo: 'user-management', pathMatch: 'full' },
     { path: 'user-management', component: UserManagmentComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard], data: {permisson:'im_user_view'}},
     { path: 'test-profile', component: TestProfileComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard], data: {permisson:'ucr_test_profile_view'}},



    canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable < boolean | UrlTree > | Promise < boolean | UrlTree > | boolean | UrlTree {
    let perm = next.data.permisson || null;

    return this.getUserInfo(perm)

    return true;
}

    getUserInfo(perm): Observable < boolean > {
        if (!perm) {
            return of(false);
        }
        return this.commonService.getUserLoggedIn().pipe(map(result => {
            if (this.PermissionService.checkPermission(perm)) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false;
            }

   })
}
```

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: yes,, how to handle permission on landing page

Comment: Well, I don't see any landing page routing. Also, can you improve the snippet formatting?

Comment: @Humberd :{ path: '', redirectTo: 'user-management', pathMatch: 'full' },

Comment: The redirect just redirects to another view. And that another view has a Guard. So if you want to have the same view without guard you have to define it again: `{path: '', component: UserManagmentComponent}`